# Where does resharper store my live templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

For some reason all my live templates are not showing up in vs.net any longer.

Where exactly does resharper save my live templates that I make?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

- ReSharper 6 and
- Visual Studio 2010 on
- Windows XP,

the Live Templates are stored in the file

- `%appdata%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.0\vs10.0\UserSettings.xml`

within the XML element `<LiveTemplatesManager>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my resharper 6.1 templates in:

```
%appdata%\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny
```

The stock templates were in:

`%appdata%\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\v6.1\vs10.0\UserSettings.xml`

within the `<LiveTemplatesManager>` XML Element